# react-native-paper mode="outlined" not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-paper

Input field border is not hiding from input field label. I tried but didn't find any solution.
this is how label is even with mode="outlined".

<del>label</del>

Comment: SHUBHAM CHAWRE I'm  facing the same issue, not sure whats wrong. Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I also use outlined inputs everywhere in my app and they work just fine.
Not sure what's wrong with your code as you haven't provided it. But styling the inputs properly, react-native-paper elements should be styled through special `theme` prop and not through basic styling. As an example:

```
theme={{ colors: { placeholder: 'white', text: 'white', primary: 'white',underlineColor:'transparent',background : '#003489'}}}
>
```

this is how would styling look like.